# How can I list partitions in storage order?

Tags: partition, fdisk, sfdisk, cfdisk

After telling general information (capacity, sector size and the like) `fdisk` shows 8 columns: sdXY, Boot, begin, end, # of sectors, size, flags, type.

The partitions get sorted by Y in their `sdXY` designations. Sometimes (i.e. when this is true) it puts a note below it, that they are not listed in storage order.

**How can I let `fdisk` (or any other appropriate tool) list the partitions on a block oriented device sorted by start sector**, i.e. by the third column **?**

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add the output of your `fdisk` and then explain what you would like to see instead. That will help clarify what you need.

Comment: Don't you mean by the second column? (this is why I asked for example input and desired output)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any program that does this, but it's easy enough to sort if all you want is the list of partitions. For example, on my system:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L7              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 97ED36D9-B503-42C1-ACE5-3E2E49212F20

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296  390625000  390057705   186G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1998360576 2000408575    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5  390625280  509251583  118626304  56.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6  509253632 1935546367 1426292736 680.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1935546368 1998360575   62814208    30G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/home: 680.1 GiB, 730253492224 bytes, 1426276352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I can sort that with:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l | grep -E '^(Devi|/dev)' | sort -nk2,2
Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296  390625000  390057705   186G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5  390625280  509251583  118626304  56.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6  509253632 1935546367 1426292736 680.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1935546368 1998360575   62814208    30G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1998360576 2000408575    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
```

The commands used are

- `grep -E '^(Devi|/dev)'`: use extended regular expressions (`-E`) which let us use `|` for "or". Then, the regular expression will match any line that begins (`^`) with either `Devi` or `/dev`.
- `sort -nk2,2`: this will sort numerically (`-n`) on the second field and only the second field (`-k2,2`) ignoring the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please explain why the ```grep -E '^(Devi|/dev)'``` part works in my German environment where the headlinbe starts with ```Gerät```?  What exactly lets ```-nk2,2``` sort by that column?

Comment: Huh. I have no idea, @AdalbertHanßen, it shouldn't catch the header if it doesn't start with `Devi`. It will catch the rest though, since the `/dev` will be the same. Are you sure it also brought the header for you? Did it maybe just show the lines beginning with `/dev` and nothing else? In any case, you can just change to `grep -E '^(Gerät|/dev)'`. For the sort, see updated answer.

Comment: Yes, ```fdisk -l /dev/sda``` also gave me the header. Your explanation is right: ```sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep -E '^/dev' | sort -nk2,2``` completely skips everything until the first line starting with ```/dev``` (in my case) and that does not depend on localization. Thank you for your advice and for the explanation. It remains unexplained, why it did noch catch the headline. Is it, because ich can't be processed by your sort by column command? - BTW: ```-nk2``` gives the same results. What's that second ```nk2,2``` good for?

Comment: ```sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep -E '^(Gerät|/dev)' | sort -nk2,2``` gives me the headline too, but it is after the first line of the table, i.e. ```/dev/sda1   *``` (the asterisk because of the bootflag) goes before the headline ```Gerät      Boot    Anfang       Ende   Sektoren  Größe Kn Typ```

Comment: Yes, exactly, @AdalbertHanßen,sorting of non ascii characters is a very complex subject that I am not qualifies to explain, but you see the header later because of the sort command. If you want more details, you can post a question about the sort order. Other users here know this kind of thing very well. Just not me, sorry.

Comment: terdon, the problem here is not the non-ascii chars but the fact that, on _mbr_ disks at least, one of the partitions might have (and usually has) the boot flag active. In that case there's an additional column named `Boot` between `Device` and `Start`  and an asterisk is present on the line that lists the bootable partition. So that line has an additional field - the 2nd field is now an asterisk and the start cylinder no. is on the 3rd field. The code just happens to work because in this case the OP has the 1st partition on disk as the bootable one and the asterisk sorts before the numbers

Comment: ...but consider a setup like [this_one](https://pastes.io/vddz8kxk3p) where the bootable partition is not the 1st partition... This is not a problem on gpt disks since there's no notion of bootable partition so one can't have an intermediate `Boot` column between `Device` and `Start` but as I said, on mbr disks, this could be a problem (admittedly, it's quite rare that the bootable partition is not the 1st one)

Comment: @don_crissti yes indeed, well spotted and yet _another_ reason why I asked the OP to provide actual output.

Comment: Agreed and this would have never occurred to me if OP hadn't made [that_comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766753/how-can-i-list-partitions-in-storage-order/766763#comment1462616_766756) about the asterisk...

Answer (score 5):

One tool that lists partitions in the order they are on disk is  `parted`so e.g. using `s`ector as unit size, if you run (as root)

```
parted /dev/sda unit s print
```

you get

```
Model: IS817 DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 15728640s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start     End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s     1435647s  1433600s  primary  ext2         boot
 4      1435648s  1640447s  204800s   primary  ext3
 2      1640448s  1644543s  4096s     primary  ntfs
 3      1644544s  1710079s  65536s    primary  fat32        lba
```

---

Another tool would be `lsblk` (no need to be root) with its `--sort` (or `-x`) option.
`lsblk` only provides the start sector of the partition so if you do not need the end sector and the size in sectors you could get an output a la `fdisk` with

```
lsblk -o name,start,size,parttype,parttypename /dev/sda
```

```
NAME     START  SIZE PARTTYPE PARTTYPENAME
sda             7,5G          
├─sda1    2048  700M 0x83     Linux
├─sda2 1640448    2M 0x7      HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
├─sda3 1644544   32M 0xc      W95 FAT32 (LBA)
└─sda4 1435648  100M 0x83     Linux
```

To sort by the start sector just add `-x start`:

```
lsblk -o name,start,size,parttype,parttypename -x start /dev/sda
```

```
NAME   START  SIZE PARTTYPE PARTTYPENAME
sda           7,5G          
sda1    2048  700M 0x83     Linux
sda4 1435648  100M 0x83     Linux
sda2 1640448    2M 0x7      HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3 1644544   32M 0xc      W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Run `lsblk --help` for a detailed list of all possible fields/columns.